# Driving through heavy rain - hazard lights on

Tags: usa, automobiles

Driving back to the Twin Cities (Minnesota, US), from a neighboring state, there was a severe rainstorm in process the entire time - near hurricane conditions. As in - there was low visibility due to the heaviness of the rainfall itself, not because of fog or anything.

Relieved to finally reach the outer limits of the cities, suddenly several cars around me had their hazard lights on!

My experience with hazard lights has been that one puts them on if pausing in a lane momentarily (to tell the drivers to go around), things like that. But not to be used while in motion.

I mean, it was easier to see the cars I guess through the heavy rain (vs just headlights/high beams). But since it was impossible to know when the driver in the next lane was going to move into my lane, and in the freeway system people are always changing lanes, I feel like it was negative overall.

Is there some signal or safety-aspect that I am unaware of?

Comment: Some places recommend (or require?) them if the speed is significantly slower than the speed limit or the expected speed (though in the described weather conditions the expected speed should probably be much lower); some places also have confusing guidelines on the use of fog lights (and the awareness of fog lights in non-foggy areas is also a problem?).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like xngtng, I had always thought that turning on your hazard lights was permitted when you're driving significantly slower than the speed limit because of weather conditions or your car is breaking down or running out of gas. Or you've stopped somewhere like a no parking/stopping zone or just on a street briefly to do something like answer your phone or look up directions. I learned to drive in Ohio and then lived in California for many years.

I found an article from 2016 in the [Atlanta Journal-Constitution newspaper](https://www.ajc.com/news/national/using-hazard-lights-rain-illegal-some-states-use-could-cost-you/4GKuiHXYiiowRgq5CgPjLP/) that lists what's permitted in each state. Note: Information may have changed since 2016. I'll excerpt the Minnesota statement.

> **Minnesota**: Hazard lights are not permitted while driving except to indicate a traffic hazard.

Most states have the same requirement--not permitted except for a traffic hazard. What exactly constitutes a 'traffic hazard' is another question.

Comment: a 'traffic hazard' would be e.g. complete stop of traffic on a highway

Comment: @Vickel true, but I assume most traffic codes don't give a complete list because conditions vary. I would consider someone traveling 20 miles below the speed limit on a freeway when it isn't congested to be a traffic hazard. Or someone carrying something that extends beyond the vehicle. Anyway, I didn't want to get into it in my answer.

Comment: In either of those examples, since the vehicle is moving, having the hazards is negative because turns can't be signalled!
And in my case of extremely heavy rain, having the hazards on to indicate the hazard of the rain itself seems unnecessary. 
So I am confused about that policy's usefulness still, but thanks for finding that reference!

Comment: @4dcndn It isn't the hazard of the rain you are indicating, but the hazard of anyone driving faster than you running into you because of lowered visibility.

Comment: Right, but throughout the hours of driving in those conditions, it was never the case that that almost happened. All of us on the freeway seemed to see each other ok, because we all gravitated to the same speed and had our headlights on, etc.. But changing lanes was much more dangerous in that final period, without having a blinker indication that that was about to happen (since hazards take away the option of using blinkers).

Comment: @4dcndn Well, you shouldn't change lanes while having the hazards on, but of course, people never do what they should do on the roads.

Comment: In France it is customary (not sure if it’s a legal requirement) that if there’s a sudden slowdown you turn your hazard lights on until the car behind you has slowed down (and turned their hazard lights on). The goal is to avoid pile-ups. Even though the official name of those lights in France is “distress lights” (_feux de détresse_) they are colloquially called “warning lights”.

Comment: @jcaron Same in Germany. People turn on the warning lights if they have to slow down significantly (say <30 km/h outside of a city) or may have come to a complete stop, particularly when reaching the tail of a traffic jam. However, once inside the traffic jam, with cars behind you that are no longer in danger of running into you, you turn it off again.

Comment: Why would you not be able to indicate changing lanes? Does your car not stop the hazard lights temporarily whilst indicating lane change?

Comment: @Mr47 In the United States, I have never seen a car where the turn signal would override the hazard lights.

Comment: @DoxyLover I learn something new everyday :) Seems to be pretty standard in Europe...

Comment: @Mr47 It is pretty standard in Europe, but European cars tend to be much more sensibly designed than US cars in many respects (see for example how many US cars have their rear turn signals integrated into their brake lights, instead of having separate lights for that purpose, which leads to all kinds of problematic implications...).

Comment: @Mr47 it's not universal for indicators to override hazard lights here in the UK, where the specifications are very similar to Europe. It might be becoming more common, but cars hang around for a long time. The use of hazards when slowing significantly is technically only meant to be on motorways here (IIRC), but fairly common on other fast roads when slowing right down abruptly

Comment: @jcaron the following car turning on their hazards is a very useful acknowledgement of the signal, which of course you don't get with  brake lights. The protocol is almost worth it for that alone.